# how to search for a string and replace it with other string in linux?

Tags: perl, shell, replace, grep

I want to **search** for a `string` and **replace** it with another `string` recursively under a directory.
for example:
I want to search for a string

`"var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");"`

and **replace** it with

`var _gaq = _gaq || [];_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7044592-1']);_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'news4u.com']);_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`

How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find` to find all files, and `xargs` to run `sed` to modify them:

```
find dir -type f | xargs sed -i.bak 's#from#to#'
```

that will find all files under *dir* and replace *from* with *to*, backing up the original files with the extension ".bak"

N.B. *from* is a basic regular expression, so you will need to escape any BRE metacharacters in the string you are searching for.  It would be a good idea to test the sed command on a single file to get it working:

```
sed 's#from#to#' file > test.out
```

That will do the replacements to *file* but instead of modifying *file* it will write the output to *test.out* so you can check the results.

Comment: I tried this below piece of code ( I am replacing with 'goo' just for testing)
`find /home/project/new4u/apps/frontend/modules/alerts/templates/testing -type f -exec sed -i "s/var gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) \? \"https:\/\/ssl.\" : \"http:\/\/www.\")/goo/" {} \;` 
It is not workign properly. I have escaped all the delimiters and still it does not work. Please let me know what changes are to be done.

Comment: You've escaped too much, `?` is not a BRE metacharacter. Also, if you quote using `'` then you don't need to escape the `"` characters, and if you use `s#from#to#` instead of `s/from/to/` then you don't need to escape the `/` characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I stopped escaping ? and " and it worked.

Comment: can you please help ne for this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411556/how-to-replace-the-following-text-using-sed)