# How to replace the following text using sed?

Tags: shell, sed, replace

Hi I want to replace `document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));`

with

`(function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();`

in all occurrences...

So i used this below code.

```
find /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/news -type f -exec sed -i s#document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));#(function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();#g {} \;
```

But it is not replacing. Is there any problem in escaping ?

Thanks

Comment: Shell will expand the double- and single quote characters. You have to quote them.

Comment: Besides, the "." (dot) has a special meaning in regexes. In this particular case, though, it unlikely to matter much.

Comment: @fork0, that won't help, the shell does word splitting too. The spaces need escaping (or quoting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the argument to sed, and escape any nested quotes. Otherwise this:

```
s#document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost +  ...
```

will be broken into separate words by the shell, instead of being passed as a single argument to sed.

You need to surround the entire sed script (the `s#from#to#` part) in quotes, I would choose single quotes, then replace every `'` in the script with `\'`.

(Also, why are you using `find -exec` instead of what I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11392128/981959)?)

Answer (score 1):

> sed -i "s/^document.write(unescape(.*;$/(function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();/" example.txt

Comment: Why not use a different delimiter such as `s#a#b#` or `s,a,b,` to avoid [leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)?

Comment: Since Javascript code often have '#' or ',' somewhere it it, and than you'll have to escape that.. I agree with you on the general case, but i think that in this case the straight forward approach might be easier to understand. I find remembering to escape '/' easier than to remember to do so for other characters.

Comment: Pick a delimiter that isn't in the string and you don't need to escape anything. Choosing a delimiter that occurs frequently in URLs when substituting bits of URLs just makes it harder than it needs to be. +1 anyway.

Comment: @Kuf I used the same as u had given. for some files it ids notchanging. 
If I `grep` for that, I get 0 count.
`$ grep -c 'document.write(unescape(*;$'  /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/news4u/apps/frontend/modules/docs/templates/vodafone-deals.htm`

Comment: I'm not sure i got you, do you mean it won't change? could you give me an example where it won't change or explain again what do you mean...

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first step would be to check the `sed` command alone:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

You have to put the sed command into single or double quotes so it is passed as a single  parameter to the sed application `'s#docum....'`. If you have single quotes within single quotes, or double quotes within double quotes you have to escape it.

Note that the command will look quite ugly, not really readable or maintainable, I would use python or ruby where you have special quotes which will help overcome with the problems of string escaping...

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's not a direct answer, for such replacement you can use "rpl" tool. 
It looks like you're using cygwin, thus you can find a win32 port [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/rpl.htm).